# How to use single DBContext in multiple identities in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-identity

I am developing a login system with ASP.NET Core Identity. I have two identities: Client and Member. When I tried to register a Member user it produces an InvalidOperationException.

ClientUser.cs

```
public class ClientUser : IdentityUser
{

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

MemberUser.cs

```
public class MemberUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string MemberFirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string MemberLastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    }
```

ClientContext.cs

```
   public class ClientContext : IdentityDbContext<ClientUser>
{
    public ClientContext(DbContextOptions<ClientContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("RazorPagesPizzaAuthConnection");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ClientContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

//builder.Services.AddDbContext<MemberContext>(options =>
//    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ClientUser>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;

}).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ClientContext>();


builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<MemberUser>()
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<MemberUser, IdentityRole>>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ClientContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddDefaultUI();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

Error:

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot create a DbSet for 'MemberUser' because this type is not included in the model for the context.

Comment: " use single DBContext in multiple identities in ASP.NET Core"  I haven't seen this approach so far. If you want two user : Client and Member , maybe you can think about [Role-based authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: I believe you can't and this is by design.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but could you want to declare ClientContext as:

```
public class ClientContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
```